# RequireJs + Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, requirejs

I'm new to RequireJs, so i little bit stuck with getting my rails 4 app working on production with requirejs pieces.

I have the following:

1) Require_rails gem

```
gem 'requirejs-rails'
```

2) Piece of require-js called in a middle of a html.erb file

```
<%= requirejs_include_tag asset_url("scribe/scribe-editor.js") %>
```

3) In this a file I have following

```
require({
  paths: {
    'scribe': 'scribe/bower_components/scribe/scribe',
    'scribe-plugin-blockquote-command': 'scribe/bower_components/scribe-plugin-blockquote-command/scribe-plugin-blockquote-command',
    'scribe-plugin-code-command': 'scribe/bower_components/scribe-plugin-code-command/scribe-plugin-code-command'
  }
}, [
  'scribe',
  'scribe-plugin-blockquote-command',
  'scribe-plugin-code-command',
], function (
  Scribe,
  scribePluginBlockquoteCommand,
  scribePluginCodeCommand,
) {
...
});
```

4) All these files located in vendor/javascripts/scribe

```
vendor/javascripts/scribe/scribe-editor.js
vendor/javascripts/scribe/bower_components/scribe/scribe.js
vendor/javascripts/scribe/bower_components/scribe/scribe/scribe-plugin-blockquote-command/scribe-plugin-blockquote-command.js
vendor/javascripts/scribe/bower_components/scribe/scribe-plugin-code-command/scribe-plugin-code-command.js
```

5) On production I have the following code.

```
<script src="/assets/require-21be67676bcf2b75c547dd382d849e26.js"></script>
<script>require.config({"baseUrl":"http://domain.com/assets","paths":{"application":"/assets/application-e720d39c2f6b94f1fd554d97b48ee312"}}); require(["http://domain.com/assets/scribe/scribe-editor-a848a8a552e89e8a8f6e9a62d10cd58f.js"]);</script>
```

6) And finally, my asset.rb file:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( 
    scribe/scribe-editor.js
)
```

=============
7) The problem: script editor is loaded, but all dependencies come with 404 not found.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not used requirejs-rails with Rails 4 yet, just rails 3.2 but I think it works mostly the same.

I think the reason you are getting those 404's for the dependencies is because r.js never ran on `scribe/scribe-editor` instead it ran on application.js which is why you see `/assets/application-e720d39c2f6b94f1fd554d97b48ee312` referenced in your production code.

First problem I see is that you are using `config.assets.precompile`. Based on the [Troubleshooting section in requirejs-rails Readme](https://github.com/jwhitley/requirejs-rails#avoid-configassetsprecompile) you should not include requirejs modules in `config.assets.precompile` since that will make rails try precompile it using sprockets. You want r.js to optimize any requirejs modules. Requirejs-rails will run r.js for you during the precompile step. In my project I use `config.assets.precompile` to compile css, an Javascript that is not a requirejs module. For instance application.js is not a requirejs module in my case (and apperently also in your case).

You don't mention whether you have a requirejs.yml file in your project. If not I suggest you add one and move your requirejs config there instead of adding it to the head of the `scribe-editor.js` module.

requrejs.yml:

```
modules:
   - name: scribe/scribe-editor
paths:
   scribe: scribe/bower_components/scribe/scribe
   scribe-plugin-blockquote-command: scribe/bower_components/scribe-plugin-blockquote-command/scribe-plugin-blockquote-command
   scribe-plugin-code-command: scribe/bower_components/scribe-plugin-code-command/scribe-plugin-code-command
```

RequireJS-Rails will use the `modules`config as part of the r.js build config to indicate what files need to be run through r.js.

RequireJS-Rails will convert the paths into Javascript and add it as a `<script>` tag before the `require.js` script tag (excluding the modules stuff) as the requirejs.config. Anything that can be in a requirejs config can be added to `requirejs.yml`

You can then change your `scribe-editor` module definition to something like:

```
define(['scribe', 'scribe-plugin-blockquote-command', 'scribe-plugin-code-command'], 
       function( Scribe, scribePluginBlockquoteCommand, scribePluginCodeCommand) {
...
});
```

Lastly I don't think you want the `asset_url()` call in `requirejs_include_tag`, you need to reference the requirejs module. Something like `<%= requirejs_include_tag('scribe/scribe-editor') %>` should work.

You should end up with 2 `script` tags added to your response in production as a result of the `requirejs_include_tag`. If I am guessing right it should look a lot like this(the SHA's I just made up):

```
<script>var require = {"baseUrl":"/assets","paths":{"scribe/scribe-editor":"/assets/scribe/scribe-editor-c48f6b842cf0f40976393a1d2f4568e0"}};</script>
<script data-main="scribe/scribe-editor-c48f6b842cf0f40976393a1d2f4568e0" src="/assets/require-cbfc3f690e2109e37e09aefd8fe40332.js"></script>
```